# Console cache: clear - Cannot declare a class already in use

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, symfony-console

I have a problem with symfony 5.1 and the `cache:clear` command line.

All of my work is working great on the browser. I've make some refactoring and move some pictures and I had a problem (it was due to a bad way), but before know this I went to clear the cache to verify.

This is what the terminal tells me:

```
$ sc cache:clear

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                                                          

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class App\Controller\Admin\Crud\UserCrudController, because the name is already in use in /home/mathieu/projets/alghazali/site/src/Controller/Admin/Crud/UserCrudController.php on line 15
10:37:38 CRITICAL  [php] Fatal Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\Controller\Admin\Crud\UserCrudController, because the name is already in use ["exception" => Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError { …}]

In UserCrudController.php line 15:
                                                                                                                        
  Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\Controller\Admin\Crud\UserCrudController, because the name is already in use  
                                                                                                                        

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>

exit status 255
```

I don't know what can I show you for better understanding.

You have maybe to know I'm using the EasyAdminBundle **3**.

This is my tree structure:

```
My-project
|
└─ src/
    ├─ .../
    |
    ├─ Controller/
    |     ├─ Admin/
    |     |     ├─ Crud/
    |     |     |    ├─ PostCrudController.php
    |     |     |    └─ UserCrudController.php
    |     |     |    
    |     |     └─ AdminDashboardController.php
    |     |
    │     ├─ MainController.php
    │     ├─ PostController.php
    │     └─ SecurityController.php
    |
    ├─ Entity/
    |     ├─ ...
    |     ├─ Post.php
    |     └─ User.php
    |
    ├─ Repository/
    |     └─ ...
    |
    └─ Kernel.php
```

In the `src/Controller/Admin/Crud/UserCrudController.php` file, I have that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Crud;

use App\Entity\User;
use ...

class UserCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
```

Comment: have you tried removing the cache manually ? with " rm -r var/cache/* "

Comment: Thanks. Yes but no change

Comment: have you tried automatically search the word "UserCrudController" in the whole project ?

Comment: I use sublime text and when I search in all project I am not capable to understand all the responses. However I have tried to rename my class and the file, and it's working

Comment: The class and the file have a new name, ok? I remove all is in /var/cache. I clear the cache then I look in /var/cache/dev/annotations.map and I find
<?php return array (
  0 => 'Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\AbstractController',
  1 => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\AdminDashboardController',
  2 => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\Crud\\PostCrudController',
  3 => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\EditorDashboadController',
  4 => 'App\\Controller\\Crud\\Admin\\UserCrudController', ...etc but EditorDashboadController and UserCrudController have been normally removed

Comment: you might have that class defined in two different files. Maybe you copied the UserCrudController.php as PostCrudController.php and forget to change the class name in PostCrudController.php? in project root on console you could type `grep -nr UserCrudController src` to find occurences (assuming bash / unix tools).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The command `$ grep -nr UserCrudController src` returns
`src/Controller/Admin/Crud/UserCrudController.php:15:class UserCrudController extends AbstractCrudController`
It is possible that I copied the file content into the other but I don't see anything weird.

Comment: Is it possible that the fact that the class was created by the command `make:admin:crud` of EasyAdminBundle and removed manually and remake manually ? I think not but now I  doubt of everything lol

Comment: Something else, when I clean the cache with the `--warm-up` option it's working correctly